# Magento 2 : 403 Forbidden Error on Checkout Through PayPal Express Checkout

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal-express

[image]

I getting this error while checkout through PayPal Express checkout. I don't know what is wrong. Anyone tell me if its PayPal configuration Error or something else along with Step by Step solution.

Also When i Tried to checkout through PayPal Sandbox buyer account i am getting this all time :
[image]

Comment: Please enable Debug Log On from Admin & check var log folder

Comment: I have checked that sometimes I got "authorization failed" error and then get payment declined on frontend

Comment: U r credentials are wrong

Comment: But i verified it again and again through account. i am using same API signature, API username & password

Comment: AnyOne who can provide me steps to configure so I can re-check where I am mistaken?

Comment: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/payment/paypal-express-checkout.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54673/discussion-between-shubham-mathur-and-ankit-shah).

Comment: https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Comment: Doesn't help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this work for me.

1) Edit /vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/web/js/action/set-payment-method.js

2) change

```
 } else {
                serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/selected-payment-method', {});
                payload = {
                    cartId: quote.getQuoteId(),
                    method: paymentData
                };
            }
```

To

```
 } else {
                serviceUrl = urlBuilder.createUrl('/carts/mine/set-payment-information', {});
                payload = {
                    cartId: quote.getQuoteId(),
                    paymentMethod: paymentData
                };
                method = 'post';
            }
```

flush cache , then deploy content and check.